# Can I export Word document(*.doc) from Reporting Service by using free component?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ms-word

I'm looking for some tool that can generate many document formats like Microsoft Excel, PDF, Microsoft Word, HTML. So, I decide to use Reporting Service of SQL Server 2008 Express. But I found that Reporting Service can't export to Microsoft Word by itself. It need to use some component. Moreover, I can't find any free component to doing this or It's impossible?

**Thanks,**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Reporting Service can't export to Microsoft Word by itself".

Reporting Services 2008 can export to all of the formats you mentioned (Excel, PDF, Word and HTML), it's one of its basic features. I've used this feature in both the express and full versions of SS2008.

See http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/reporting.aspx

Comment: How to generate Microsoft Word 2007(*.docx) from Reporting Service?

Comment: In short, there's lots of ways. In development, when you run a report there is a drop down which allows you to chose a render type. In Report Manager (the online GUI for a report server) when you run a report there is a drop down which allows you to chose a render type. If you access the report via a url (see beakersoft's answer) you can choose a format option. If you access the report via the web service (eg: through a .NET application) you can set the Format option there too.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned reporting services can already export in these formats, you can also specify on the url if you want to render the report in another format instead of as a webpage, like this:

http:///reportserver?/Sales/YearlySalesSummary**&rs:Format=HTML4.0&rs:Command=Render**

See - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154040.aspx

You can also get the reports to export in these formats if you are running the reports of a schedule