# Binding C# object as datasource To A SSRS Report

Tags: c#, data-binding, reporting-services

I've a C# object like:

```
public class PersonDetails
{
    public string Name1{get; set;}
    ... ... ...
    public string Name2{get; set;}
    ... ... ...
    public string Name2{get; set;}
    ... ... ...
}
```

I want to bind a collection of this class to a SSRS report:

[image: SSRS_Report]

Those are all text boxes. But the report ultimately shows the first item in the collection.
I'm binding the report like this:

```
    this.PersonDetailsPostBindingSource.DataSource = _personDetailsPostCollection.PersonDetailsPostList;

    this.reportViewerPersonDetailsPost.RefreshReport();
```

Where `PersonDetailsPostList` is a list of the class objects.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking its bc you are using `=First(...)` in your RDL  `First` always gives you the first item in the list.

Comment: Thanks. For your help. Can you say is there any way to export report to word. In mine only shows PDF and Excel.

Comment: you should look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963594/can-i-export-word-document-doc-from-reporting-service-by-using-free-component "")